# Compiling tensorflow serving protos

Tags: tensorflow, go, protocol-buffers, tensorflow-serving, protoc

I've been trying to request a tensorflow serving model however I need to serialize & encode the data so I've been trying to compile tensorflow serving protos into golang following [this](https://blog.ukjae.io/posts/tensorflow-serving-apis-proto/) tutorial.

However I'm stuck when trying to compile the pruned protos into Go.

My folder structure is:

```
main_folder:
  - tensorflow_serving:
     - apis
     - config
  - tensorflow:
     - core:
       - example
       - framework
       - protobuf
  - output_dir:
```

Being in the main folder directly, I've managed to compile them using

```
protoc --go_out=./output_dir tensorflow/*/*/*.proto
```

However using the same command :

```
protoc --go_out=./output_dir tensorflow_serving/*/*.proto
```

I get an error saying that:

```
protoc-gen-go: unable to determine Go import path for "tensorflow_serving/apis/input.proto"

Please specify either:
    • a "go_package" option in the .proto source file, or
    • a "M" argument on the command line.

See https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#package for more information.

--go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

My tensorflow_serving protos often try importing from tensorflow and I suspect it's a question of managing to link properly, but I cannot find how

I tried adding

```
--proto_path=./tensorflow --proto_path=./tensorflow_serving
```

without success